# jQuery show/hide not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic html page with some JS and CSS:

```js
$('.expand').click(function() {
  $('.img_display_content').show();
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.wrap {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.img_display_header {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  display: block;
  border: #333 solid 1px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.expand {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img_display_content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0F3;
  margin-top: -2px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="beta.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="img_display_header">
      <div class="expand">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="img_display_content"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

A click on the `div` with the class `expand` does nothing...
I also have tried to copy/paste an example code from jQuery website but it also didn't work.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: There is not the `img_display_content` div is showing when the javascript is defined, check it out http://jsfiddle.net/8z52e/

Comment: The code seems ok DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1773/

Comment: the problem is that you attach the click handler before the DOM is loaded, you need to wrap your code in a function that runs after DOM is ready

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add the document ready function, this way it waits until the ***DOM*** has been loaded, also by using the `:visible` pseudo you can write a simple show and hide function.

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/NER5w/1/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $( '.expand' ).click(function() {
         if($( '.img_display_content' ).is(":visible")){
              $( '.img_display_content' ).hide();
         } else{
              $( '.img_display_content' ).show();
         }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Demo

```js
$( '.expand' ).click(function() {
  $( '.img_display_content' ).toggle();
});
```

```css
.wrap {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:40%;
}

.img_display_header {
    height:20px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    display:block;
    border:#333 solid 1px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.expand {
 float:right;
 height: 100%;
 padding-right:5px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.img_display_content {
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;   
    background-color:#0F3;
    margin-top: -2px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="img_display_header">
<div class="expand">+</div>
</div>
<div class="img_display_content"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
"Display or hide the matched elements."

This is much shorter in code than using show() and hide() methods.

Comment: js fiddle I forgot to set the function to be invoked ondomready. Fixed that.

Comment: I guarantee the OP's next question will be "How can I change the + to - when it's visible"

Answer (score 4):

In my case it wasn't working because the containing div I was trying to hide had Bootstrap flex properties applied inline in the html.  Once I moved everything into a parent div without any bootstrap classes, now hide works.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( '.expand' ).click(function() {
        $( '.img_display_content' ).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Event assigning always after Document Object Model loaded

Comment: With the show method() alone you cannot hide it again.

Comment: I solved the problem in question. not someone I correct functionality

Answer (score 2):

The content is not ready yet, you can move your js to the end of the file or do

```
<script>
$(function () { 
    $( '.expand' ).click(function() {
       $( '.img_display_content' ).show();
    });
});
```

So that the document waits to be loaded before running.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (grid.selectedKeyNames().length > 0) {
            $('#btnRemoveFromList').show();
        } else {
            $('#btnRemoveFromList').hide();
        }

}
```

`()` - calls the method

no parentheses - returns the property